# Python converting numerical data back to categorial

Tags: python

I had some categorical data,  I converted them to numerical value. I used k-mean algorithm to cluster the numerical data. Now I want to visualise the data showing the categorical value. How can I change numerical value back to categorical value?

Comment: A category has less information than a number. So yo can't.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not quite clear, mainly because you do not show an example. Please show example input and the desired output. Also show any more thoughts you have on the problem and any code attempts. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).